# How to make Direct2D treat D2D1_COLOR_F as sRGB?

Tags: winapi, colors, direct2d

I have a Win32 non-game windowed app that uses a Direct2D device context/HWND render target to draw a window (think Notepad, not a fullscreen game).

Currently `D2D1_COLOR_F` is treated as being in the device colorspace, e.g. on a wide gamut display the `#ff0000` color (red) is treated as the maximum red the monitor can display (and in this case is quite an intense red).

The question is: **how to make Direct2D treat `D2D1_COLOR_F` inputs (e.g. to `FillRectangle()` or `DrawTextLayout()`) as in the sRGB colorspace instead?**

For an illustration of the difference, try searching for "red" in both Chrome and Firefox on Windows on a wide gamut display, and compare the difference - Chrome uses sRGB and the red is rather subdued, while Firefox uses the device colorspace, and the red in it is the most saturated red possible.

**Details**

The swap chain buffers are created with `::D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)`. I tried `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM_SRGB`, but that got rejected as an incompatible format.

Comment: Is there any run-able code sample demo difference color between D2D1_COLOR_F and sRGB?